# Screen job not working in AWS EC@ crontab

Tags: cron

"45 05 * * 1-5 screen -dmS sample python3 /home/ec2-user/Check_Print_Numbers.py" - This detached screen job is not working in crontab whereas "screen -dmS sample python3 /home/ec2-user/Check_Print_Numbers.py" is perfectly working if triggered outside crontab.